# How can I create a downloadable VrCard on my flask web page?

Tags: python, html, flask, vcf-vcard

I would like to create a vcf file on my website that users can download and add the file info to their contacts on their mobile phones.

So far I have made this:

```
  <a href="'data:text/vcard'" download="vcard.vcf">Download</a>
```

When I click the link it downloads a vcf file. When I open it, it redirects me to my contacts app and throws me this error: "No importable cards were found." That´s because I haven´t set any information in any VCard. I would like to know how can I set/create a VCard with the information I have in my SQLAlchemy database (name, email,phonenumber,website,etc.) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this problem recently for work. [Here is how I did it!](https://gist.github.com/tomthorogood/a2429249266070b2f5bbbaebfc2c7778)

The broad strokes: Created a Jinja2 template based on my team's needs for vcard output, a data model to lay over the template, a service to render the template from the database query, and finally, using `io.BytesIO` and `flask.send_file` to transmit the data in file format to the user.

The gist linked above doesn't have the more contextual parts of the implementation, but does provide an example of how to wire up flask to do this.

Edit: I evaluated the `vobject` library that i found recommended, but I honestly didn't think it was intuitive to use *or* very pythonic, meaning it wasn't something I wanted to depend on in my code base. However, maybe it'll work better for you (or others).